# The image is not changing when it collapses back (jquery, css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, woocommerce

The image will change when it expands, but when it collapses back, it won't change, my code looks like below:

**JS:**

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Categories menu opening
        $('.woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.cat-parent').prepend('<div class="cat-menu-close"></div>');

        $(document).on("click", ".woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.cat-parent > .cat-menu-close", function (e) {
            var $catParent = $(this).closest('li.cat-parent');
            var state = $catParent.hasClass('close');

            $catParent.toggleClass('opened', !state);

            $(this).nextAll('ul.children:first').slideToggle(state);

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS:**

```
.woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li .cat-menu-close {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     line-height: 20px;
     text-align: center;
     cursor: pointer;
     top: 4px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
}
 .woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li > .cat-menu- close:hover {
     opacity: 0.5;
}
 .woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li > .cat-menu- close:after {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 2px;
     background: url("../img/arrow-right.svg") no-repeat center center;
     background-size: 20px 20px;
     width: 10px;
     height: 20px;
     content: "";
}
 .woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.opened > .cat- menu-close:after {
     background: url("../img/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
     background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

Could someone help? I need to change the image when it expands and collapses, thank you and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that the category even after the SlideUp stays like this

`class="cat-item cat-item-69 cat-parent opened"`

instead of returning to it's original state that is

`class="cat-item cat-item-69 cat-parent"`

I am trying to find out the reason myself but I have too little experience with js so it's kinda hard to figure it out.

now if you remove the `"!"` from

`$catParent.toggleClass('opened', !state);`

the image will stop moving in general as it will not change the state.

**edited answer bellow**

Alright I have solved the riddle

After a bit of trial and error, I have your answer. In your code you have this:

```
        var $catParent = $(this).closest('li.cat-parent');
        var state = $catParent.hasClass('close');

        $catParent.toggleClass('opened', !state);
```

this part of the code sets the starting state "close"

```
        var state = $catParent.hasClass('close');
```

and when you click you get the state "opened" with the

```
        $catParent.toggleClass('opened', !state);
```

This doesn't give you the option to change back to the original state onclick as the "opened" state is set to as important with the exclamation mark. 
Now if you edit your code to set two variable states as opened and close. and then leave the toggleClass to change between the states you get the outcome you want. I am not sure if my explanation is correct but here is the code you need.
I have already tested it and I am using it on the [webpage](https://medicalfa.gr) I am administrating if you want you can check it out

```
// Categories menu opening
$('.woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.cat-parent').prepend('<div class="cat-menu-close"></div>');

$(document).on("click", ".woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.cat-parent > .cat-menu-close", function(e) {
var $catParent = $(this).closest('li.cat-parent');
var state = 'close'
var state = 'opened'


$catParent.toggleClass(state);


$(this).nextAll('ul.children:first').slideToggle(state);
```

**[Edit]**

To anyone checking out this answer I would better recommend another plugin named 'WooCommerce Product Categories Selection' as it seems to be functioning way better.

I am using it on my websites now, the only downside is that it doesn't have icons for expand and collapse but it's really easy to add it, and if you do decide to go that way you may like find [this solution helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065324/add-image-in-javascript)

Comment: Cheers mate, no problem at all.