# add image in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress plugin (open source) that will allow you to add an expandable widget for a WooCommerce product category.

**This is the JS:**

```
    // mtree.js
// Requires jquery.js and velocity.js (optional but recommended).
// Copy the below function, add to your JS, and simply add a list <ul class=mtree> ... </ul>
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

  // Only apply if mtree list exists
  if($('ul.mtree').length) { 


  // Settings
  var collapsed = true; // Start with collapsed menu (only level 1 items visible)
  var close_same_level = true; // Close elements on same level when opening new node.
  var duration = mtree_options.duration; // Animation duration should be tweaked according to easing.
  var listAnim = true; // Animate separate list items on open/close element (velocity.js only).
  var easing = mtree_options.easing_type; // Velocity.js only, defaults to 'swing' with jquery animation.

  // Set initial styles 
  $('.mtree ul').css({'overflow':'hidden', 'height': (collapsed) ? 0 : 'auto', 'display': (collapsed) ? 'none' : 'block' });

  // Get node elements, and add classes for styling
  var node = $('.mtree li:has(ul)');  
  node.each(function(index, val) {
    $(this).children(':first-child').css('cursor', 'pointer')
    $(this).addClass('mtree-node mtree-' + ((collapsed) ? 'closed' : 'open'));
    $(this).children('ul').addClass('mtree-level-' + ($(this).parentsUntil($('ul.mtree'), 'ul').length + 1));
  });

  // Set mtree-active class on list items for last opened element
  $('.mtree li > *:first-child').on('click.mtree-active', function(e){
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('mtree-closed')) {
      $('.mtree-active').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('mtree-active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('mtree-active');
    } else if($(this).parent().hasClass('mtree-open')){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('mtree-active'); 
    } else {
      $('.mtree-active').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('mtree-active');
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('mtree-active'); 
    }
  });

  // Set node click elements, preferably <a> but node links can be <span> also
  node.children(':first-child').on('click.mtree', function(e){

    // element vars
    var el = $(this).parent().children('ul').first();
    var isOpen = $(this).parent().hasClass('mtree-open');

    // close other elements on same level if opening 
    if((close_same_level || $('.csl').hasClass('active')) && !isOpen) {
      var close_items = $(this).closest('ul').children('.mtree-open').not($(this).parent()).children('ul');

      // Velocity.js
      if($.Velocity) {
        close_items.velocity({
          height: 0
        }, {
          duration: duration,
          easing: easing,
          display: 'none',
          delay: 100,
          complete: function(){
            setNodeClass($(this).parent(), true)
          }
        });

      // jQuery fallback
      } else {
        close_items.delay(100).slideToggle(duration, function(){
          setNodeClass($(this).parent(), true);
        });
      }
    }

    // force auto height of element so actual height can be extracted
    el.css({'height': 'auto'}); 

    // listAnim: animate child elements when opening
    if(!isOpen && $.Velocity && listAnim) el.find(' > li, li.mtree-open > ul > li').css({'opacity':0}).velocity('stop').velocity('list');

    // Velocity.js animate element
    if($.Velocity) {
      el.velocity('stop').velocity({
        //translateZ: 0, // optional hardware-acceleration is automatic on mobile
        height: isOpen ? [0, el.outerHeight()] : [el.outerHeight(), 0]
      },{
        queue: false,
        duration: duration,
        easing: easing,
        display: isOpen ? 'none' : 'block',
        begin: setNodeClass($(this).parent(), isOpen),
        complete: function(){
          if(!isOpen) $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        }
      });

    // jQuery fallback animate element
    } else {
      setNodeClass($(this).parent(), isOpen);
      el.slideToggle(duration);
    }

    // We can't have nodes as links unfortunately
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Function for updating node class
  function setNodeClass(el, isOpen) {
    if(isOpen) {
      el.removeClass('mtree-open').addClass('mtree-closed');
    } else {
      el.removeClass('mtree-closed').addClass('mtree-open');
    }
  }

  // List animation sequence
  if($.Velocity && listAnim) {
    $.Velocity.Sequences.list = function (element, options, index, size) {
      $.Velocity.animate(element, { 
        opacity: [1,0],
        translateY: [0, -(index+1)]
      }, {
        delay: index*(duration/size/2),
        duration: duration,
        easing: easing
      });
    };
  }

    // Fade in mtree after classes are added.
    // Useful if you have set collapsed = true or applied styles that change the structure so the menu doesn't jump between states after the function executes.
    if($('.mtree').css('opacity') == 0) {
      if($.Velocity) {
        $('.mtree').css('opacity', 1).children().css('opacity', 0).velocity('list');
      } else {
        $('.mtree').show(200);
      }
    }
  }
}(jQuery, this, this.document));
```

I've added a background image using CSS and :before but the image is not clickable.

Is there a way to add it on the JS so that it can be clicked as well?

I've tried to see where to add some code but actually I'm clueless, should it be between lines 29 and 37?

You can see it in: https://tester.medicalfa.gr/test/katastima/

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865790/adding-image-using-javascript

Comment: I did find that but I am not sure where to add the code that is my main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it via css, the arrows now appears like they are clickable.
The solution is to remove the code I had added:

```
ul.mtree.default li.mtree-open:before {
     display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 200px;
        background: url("../images/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 20px 20px;
    }
```

I removed the :before as it adds the arrow behind the text and now appears after the text as it's supposed to.

**The code looks like this now:**

```
ul.mtree.default li.mtree-open {
 display: block ;
    background: url("../images/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    background-position:top right;
}
```